What materials minimize guitar pick chirp (squeak)?
I've had to switch to a rigid thumbpick for guitar playing, but the picks I'm currently using have a lot of high-frequency squeak, called "pick chirp."
What materials minimize guitar pick chirp?
This video demonstrates pick chirp:
https://ironageaccessories.com/blogs/iron-age-general-blog/guitar-pick-noise-pick-chirp

Are you sure you're not hearing squeaking from the fretting hand?

@phoog My guess is that the question is about a squeaking sound at the very beginning of the note. Not sure if the pick material affects it much, but I'm interested to see the answers.

@user1079505 I am unfamiliar with any such squeak.  I also find it difficult to imagine how the onset of a picked note might include any sound described as a "squeak," though perhaps not impossible -- I'm not sure I can think of a better word.  Nevertheless, in my understanding "squeak" implies a duration of sound that is somewhat longer than the attack of a plucked string.  By contrast, the squeak of fingertips that have molded themselves to the winding on the lower strings as they slide up or down is prominent in many guitar performances.

@phoog maybe we need to ask the OP to clarify and provide examples.

Really, we need far more information. A sound bite would be of great help. Does it happen on every string, every fret? Do you hold your pick so there's a lot to play the strings with?

Are you possibly referring to the squeak that results from the pick's contact muting the string during contact, except for some high harmonic, which is then boosted to a loud squeak by your high gain amp?

The clicking sound of a pick can be annoying but squeak is associated with fingers rubbing on strings when fretting.

I agree with others: please clarify what kind of squeak this is about and ideally post an audio example.

Googling "thumbpicks squeaking" turns up a couple pages of a banjo forum with lots of suggestions. The one about the Sharpie sounds promising.

Cruising the web, the consensus is that nylon, Tortex, and Delrin are the best materials for reducing pick chirp.
Sources:

https://ironageaccessories.com/blogs/iron-age-general-blog/guitar-pick-noise-pick-chirp
https://www.reddit.com/r/Guitar/comments/1blvhwo/how_to_avoid_chirp_sound_that_comes_with_thicker/
https://www.jazzguitar.be/forum/guitar-amps-gizmos/71946-thick-guitar-pick-does-not-chirp-click.html


Aside from unusual things like metal, are there any materials used for picks besides nylon, tortex, and delrin?

Celluloid and casein.  There is a noticeable difference between celluloid and tortex pick noise ime. Celluloid is a harder material.

@Edward I had thought that Tortex was a name brand for celluloid, and it's not, it's a name brand for a plastic not made from nitrocellulose. But celluloid is softer than Tortex and Delrin, according to sources I found.

Looking at the first video suggests that a different technique would eliminate the chirp much more than changing picks. Not using the edge of the pick to pick and preparing the stroke by leaving the pick in contact with the string as long as possible would serve to prevent activating the string with pick contact. Your first video also suggests picking right on top of the pickup to eliminate chirp.
